# How to manage logs for website as website stops to work sometimes in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an IIS hosted website hosted on a Windows Server 2012 R2. But I am having a problem with it. Sometimes the website suddenly stops working and after a few minutes, it starts to work again.

I have reviewed some of the log files. There are hundreds of entries. I have filtered on a few unique entries. The following is one example :

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2016-12-15 08:43:18
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
```

Can anybody help me to understand the above log? Are there any other log entries I could review to help identify the issue?

Let me tell you one more thing that I have updated in the last few days in my code. I have updated a few product names and the SKU. Previous URLs of Google now redirect to a new URL. I might have missed some of the previous URLs. I don't think that this change would create this problem, but worth a mention.

Comment: i would recommend [Elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/), i think this can help, plus it has and email notify modul (if i am not mistaken)

Comment: @BMaximus Thanks, I will use it but how can I identify issue currently. I have log but I don't know how to identify. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example log you've supplied only shows the log file header columns, not any actual data. The iis log file should be capturing requests to the web site, eg '2016-12-15 16:19:32 172.31.4.72 GET /website/pagename.aspx and - other stuff - here - etc'.

Another area to investigate is the server's Event Viewer log. Open Event Viewer, then look in the Windows Logs/Application section. Look for events that happened around the same time that your web site stopped working, in particular anything with a source of 'ASP.NET'. If the web site stopped due to an error, something should be logged in here.